# How Do I Format My Currency and Decimal in a SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, db2

I have a SQL select statement that doesnt want to format my $ values correctly. The $ ammount returned should be 95,399,927.38 instead I get 9,539,927,385.00 I tried DECIMAL() a few different ways. What Am I missing? My info on the field is below.

In the past I just formatted it in Excel when I pulled in my data but this one isnt going to be in Excel.

```
COLUMN_NAME SXAS01
DATA_TYPE   3
TYPE_NAME   DECIMAL
COLUMN_SIZE 15
BUFFER_LENGTH   17
DECIMAL_DIGITS  0
NUM_PREC_RADIX  10
NULLABLE    0
REMARKS (null)
COLUMN_DEF  0
SQL_DATA_TYPE   3
SQL_DATETIME_SUB    (null)
CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH   (null)
ORDINAL_POSITION    11
IS_NULLABLE NO
```

Formatted it perfectly.
select decimal(SXAS01,9,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it sql server?
You could try

```
SELECT CONVERT(Decimal(9,2), SXAS01)
```

Or

```
select CAST(SXAS01 AS decimal(10,1))
```

DB2
You can try

```
select decimal(SXAS01,9,2)
```

OR

```
select DEC(SXAS01,9,2)
```